# Error in calling adView programmatically?

Tags: android, admob

I am calling the Admob ad in my app programmatically. 
First I am declaring the imports

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
```

Then defining my adid as string

```
String my_ad_unit_id="*some number*";
```

calling the ad as -

```
this.adView=new AdView (this,AdSize.BANNER,this.my_ad_unit_id);
((LinearLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.main)).addView(this.adView);
this.adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

There is error only in the calling part. The errors are -

- adView cannot be resolve a part
- AdView() in AdView cannot be applied to:
- AdRequest '(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.Builder)' has private access in 'com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest'

Comment: Till now I solved the first problem by declaring AdView adView; but other 2 are still in same state

Answer (score 6):

You've imported classes from the google play services library but you're using the older admob api.

If you're using admob via the google play services library, make the following changes to your code:

```
     adView = new AdView(this);
     adView.setAdUnitId(); 
     adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
     AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
     adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

If you are using the old GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar, make sure you import from the right packages:

```
import com.google.ads.Ad;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;
```

Comment: Hi! I am using Google Play services hence Admob in it

Comment: Then use the first part of the code like I've described above